# Can not set EJB in Named Bean

Tags: jsf, dependency-injection, cdi, jsf-2.2

I'm getting the same exception ever and ever.

I have 4 Named Beans and one of them is a SessionScoped Bean that store the user session. This bean is injected into another bean with @Inject. I'm using JSF 2.2.

This is the code:

```
package vista;


import modelo.Contacto;
import modelo.Usuario;
import negocio.Negocio;


import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;


@Named
@SessionScoped
public class InfoSesion implements Serializable{

    @Inject
    private Negocio negocio;

    private Usuario usuario;

    /**
     * Creates a new instance of InfoSesion
     */
    public InfoSesion() {
    }

    public synchronized void setUsuario(Usuario usuario) {
        this.usuario = usuario;
    }

    public synchronized Usuario getUsuario() {
        return usuario;
    }

    public synchronized List<Contacto> getContactos()
    {
        if (usuario != null)
        {
            return usuario.getContactos();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public synchronized String invalidarSesion()
    {
        if (usuario != null)
        {
            usuario = null;
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().invalidateSession();
        }
        return "login.xhtml";
    }

    public synchronized void refrescarUsuario()
    {
        if (usuario != null)
        {
            usuario = negocio.refrescarUsuario(usuario);
            System.out.println(usuario.getContactos().size());
        }
    }
}
```

In this view I use infoSesion:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:c="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsp/jstl/core">

<h:head>
    <title>Login de usuario</title>
</h:head>

<h:body>
    <h:form id="login">

        <c:choose>
            <c:when test="#{!empty infoSesion.usuario}">
                <p>Está autenticado como <h:outputText value="#{infoSesion.usuario.cuenta}"/>.</p>
                <p>Para iniciar sesión con otra cuenta debe <h:commandLink action="#{infoSesion.invalidarSesion()}">salir</h:commandLink> primero de la aplicación</p>
            </c:when>

            <c:otherwise>
                <h:panelGrid columns="3">
                    <h:outputText value="Nombre de usuario:"/>
                    <h:inputText id="user" required="true" value="#{login.usuario.cuenta}"/>
                    <h:message for="user"/>

                    <h:outputText value="Contraseña:"/>
                    <h:inputSecret id="pass" required="true" value="#{login.usuario.password}"/>
                    <h:message for="pass"/>

                    <h:commandButton value="Entrar" action="#{login.entrar()}"/>

                </h:panelGrid>

                <div>
                    <p>Si no tiene cuenta puede crear una en la <h:link outcome="registroUsuario.xhtml">página de registro</h:link></p>
                </div>

            </c:otherwise>
        </c:choose>




    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Here is the Exception:

```
14:07:54,689 FATAL [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.context] (default task-1) JSF1073: se ha interceptado javax.faces.view.facelets.TagAttributeException durante el procesamiento de RENDER_RESPONSE 6 : UIComponent-ClientId=, Mensaje=/login.xhtml @16,57 test="#{!empty infoSesion.usuario}" Can not set negocio.Negocio field vista.InfoSesion.negocio to negocio.Negocio$1191481171$Proxy$_$$_Weld$EnterpriseProxy$
14:07:54,691 FATAL [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.context] (default task-1) /login.xhtml @16,57 test="#{!empty infoSesion.usuario}" Can not set negocio.Negocio field vista.InfoSesion.negocio to negocio.Negocio$1191481171$Proxy$_$$_Weld$EnterpriseProxy$: javax.faces.view.facelets.TagAttributeException: /login.xhtml @16,57 test="#{!empty infoSesion.usuario}" Can not set negocio.Negocio field vista.InfoSesion.negocio to negocio.Negocio$1191481171$Proxy$_$$_Weld$EnterpriseProxy$
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.TagAttributeImpl.getObject(TagAttributeImpl.java:358) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.TagAttributeImpl.getBoolean(TagAttributeImpl.java:150) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jstl.core.ChooseWhenHandler.isTestTrue(ChooseWhenHandler.java:87) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jstl.core.ChooseHandler.apply(ChooseHandler.java:104) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:203) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:203) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:95) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:93) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:87) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.apply(DefaultFacelet.java:161) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.buildView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:990) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:99) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:61) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:56) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:45) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:63) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:70) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:261) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:247) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:76) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:166) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:197) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:759) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set negocio.Negocio field vista.InfoSesion.negocio to negocio.Negocio$1191481171$Proxy$_$$_Weld$EnterpriseProxy$
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:164) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:168) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.set(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:81) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Field.java:741) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.FieldInjectionPoint.inject(FieldInjectionPoint.java:94) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]
    at org.jboss.weld.util.Beans.injectBoundFields(Beans.java:370) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]
    at org.jboss.weld.util.Beans.injectFieldsAndInitializers(Beans.java:381) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.ResourceInjector$1.proceed(ResourceInjector.java:70) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.InjectionContextImpl.run(InjectionContextImpl.java:48) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.ResourceInjector.inject(ResourceInjector.java:72) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.BasicInjectionTarget.inject(BasicInjectionTarget.java:121) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean.create(ManagedBean.java:150) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]
    at org.jboss.weld.context.unbound.DependentContextImpl.get(DependentContextImpl.java:69) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:742) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]
    at org.jboss.weld.el.AbstractWeldELResolver.lookup(AbstractWeldELResolver.java:120) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]
    at org.jboss.weld.el.AbstractWeldELResolver.getValue(AbstractWeldELResolver.java:90) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]
    at org.jboss.as.jsf.injection.weld.ForwardingELResolver.getValue(ForwardingELResolver.java:46) [wildfly-jsf-injection-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:188) [jboss-el-api_3.0_spec-1.0.3.Final.jar:1.0.3.Final]
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:116) [javax.el-3.0.1-b05.jar:]
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getBase(AstValue.java:151) [javax.el-3.0.1-b05.jar:]
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:200) [javax.el-3.0.1-b05.jar:]
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstEmpty.getValue(AstEmpty.java:66) [javax.el-3.0.1-b05.jar:]
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstNot.getValue(AstNot.java:63) [javax.el-3.0.1-b05.jar:]
    at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:226) [javax.el-3.0.1-b05.jar:]
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.TagAttributeImpl.getObject(TagAttributeImpl.java:356) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    ... 44 more

14:07:55,349 FATAL [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.context] (default task-3) JSF1073: se ha interceptado javax.faces.view.facelets.TagAttributeException durante el procesamiento de RENDER_RESPONSE 6 : UIComponent-ClientId=, Mensaje=/login.xhtml @16,57 test="#{!empty infoSesion.usuario}" Can not set negocio.Negocio field vista.InfoSesion.negocio to negocio.Negocio$1191481171$Proxy$_$$_Weld$EnterpriseProxy$
14:07:55,353 FATAL [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.context] (default task-3) /login.xhtml @16,57 test="#{!empty infoSesion.usuario}" Can not set negocio.Negocio field vista.InfoSesion.negocio to negocio.Negocio$1191481171$Proxy$_$$_Weld$EnterpriseProxy$: javax.faces.view.facelets.TagAttributeException: /login.xhtml @16,57 test="#{!empty infoSesion.usuario}" Can not set negocio.Negocio field vista.InfoSesion.negocio to negocio.Negocio$1191481171$Proxy$_$$_Weld$EnterpriseProxy$
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.TagAttributeImpl.getObject(TagAttributeImpl.java:358) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.TagAttributeImpl.getBoolean(TagAttributeImpl.java:150) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jstl.core.ChooseWhenHandler.isTestTrue(ChooseWhenHandler.java:87) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jstl.core.ChooseHandler.apply(ChooseHandler.java:104) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:203) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:203) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:95) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:93) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:87) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.apply(DefaultFacelet.java:161) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.buildView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:990) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:99) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:61) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:56) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:45) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:63) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:70) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:261) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:247) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:76) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:166) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:197) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:759) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set negocio.Negocio field vista.InfoSesion.negocio to negocio.Negocio$1191481171$Proxy$_$$_Weld$EnterpriseProxy$
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:164) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:168) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.set(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:81) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Field.java:741) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.FieldInjectionPoint.inject(FieldInjectionPoint.java:94) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]
    at org.jboss.weld.util.Beans.injectBoundFields(Beans.java:370) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]
    at org.jboss.weld.util.Beans.injectFieldsAndInitializers(Beans.java:381) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.ResourceInjector$1.proceed(ResourceInjector.java:70) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.InjectionContextImpl.run(InjectionContextImpl.java:48) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.ResourceInjector.inject(ResourceInjector.java:72) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.BasicInjectionTarget.inject(BasicInjectionTarget.java:121) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean.create(ManagedBean.java:150) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]
    at org.jboss.weld.context.unbound.DependentContextImpl.get(DependentContextImpl.java:69) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:742) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]
    at org.jboss.weld.el.AbstractWeldELResolver.lookup(AbstractWeldELResolver.java:120) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]
    at org.jboss.weld.el.AbstractWeldELResolver.getValue(AbstractWeldELResolver.java:90) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]
    at org.jboss.as.jsf.injection.weld.ForwardingELResolver.getValue(ForwardingELResolver.java:46) [wildfly-jsf-injection-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:188) [jboss-el-api_3.0_spec-1.0.3.Final.jar:1.0.3.Final]
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:116) [javax.el-3.0.1-b05.jar:]
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getBase(AstValue.java:151) [javax.el-3.0.1-b05.jar:]
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:200) [javax.el-3.0.1-b05.jar:]
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstEmpty.getValue(AstEmpty.java:66) [javax.el-3.0.1-b05.jar:]
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstNot.getValue(AstNot.java:63) [javax.el-3.0.1-b05.jar:]
    at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:226) [javax.el-3.0.1-b05.jar:]
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.TagAttributeImpl.getObject(TagAttributeImpl.java:356) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    ... 44 more
```

I'm using WildFly 8.2.0, Java EE 7.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you post the exception in text? is hard to read... ;)

Comment: Look at the stack trace.
Null Pointer occurs in vista.Registro

Comment: For every managed-bean apart, if you annotate it by `@Named` then inject the EJB by `@Inject`, or if you annotate it by `@ManagedBean`, then inject the EJB by `@EJB`. These are couple annotations, they cannot be mixed.

Comment: Thanks for the answers.

Omar, I change the `@EJB` annotation for the `@Inject` annotation and I'm getting the same Exception, your solution don't work for me :(

Comment: Yes, the line that produced the null pointer exception is:


`if (!usuario.getPassword().equals(repass))`

The atributte usuario is null, but I don't know why.

Comment: I'm asking because this code is working fine in Glassfish 4.1 but not in WildFly 8.2.0.

The problem is not that I do not know that is a null variable, the real problem is that I'm new with Java EE and I'm learning the basics with a little application example. 
I'm sure that the fault is in @Inject the EJB and the initialization of usuario var.

Comment: This is not a session scoped bean as you are likely to believe literally. The bean is instead designated with a dependent pseudo scope as it is decorated by a JSF specific annotation `javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped`. It will be ignored in its entirely and the default CDI scope which is `@Dependent`  will come into play. You need a CDI specific annotation `javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped` and synchronizing methods using `synchronized` is unnecessary (nor you need a session scoped bean for this kind of things but it depends. I choose to remain completely mute about it).

Comment: Well, I understand the change to `enterprise.context.SessionScoped`. But when I change the import, Intellij IDEA is telling me that cannot Inject the EJB. What is the correct way for store the user sesion?

Comment: Injecting an EJB into a CDI bean or injecting a CDI bean into another CDI bean in this way should cause any problem. Despite the IDE's warning, if it functions correctly, you can safely ignore the IDE's warning(s), if any provided that the container itself does not suffer from any long-held/long-running bug that may affect the underlying CDI implementation (Weld or so).